# cannot access org.jooq.TableField

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jooq, pants

A [jooq](https://www.jooq.org/) question;

Things I did:

1. wrote my *.sql file
2. ran

> ./pants jooq myApp/myApp-jooq:jooq

which generates all of the table classes.

3. then I was trying to write my Java sql classes to do CRUD operations against my DB, but I got these exceptions:

> Cannot access org.jooq.Scope
>
> Cannot access org.jooq.TableField
>
> Cannot access org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl

in three different places.

I don't really understand how this could happen, I had been doing the same thing for my other two apps and they had been working perfectly fine, and hang out on www.jooq.org didn't lend me any valuable info for this case.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved, it turns out that I'm missing a BUILD depedency in my BUILD file, after adding

> 'myApp/myApp-jooq:lib',

into my BUILD file, this error is gone.

Thanks.